# Is there Gnome40 stable version for 20.04 ? if yes how to download it?

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I am not able to find gnome40 stable build am new and currently on 20.04 LTS 3.36 .

Comment: You're correct, it is not available in 20.04 [According to the package repos](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gnome&searchon=names), GNOME 40+ is only in Impish or later. There might be something like [Debian Backports](https://backports.debian.org/) for Ubuntu, but I'm not sure

Comment: That would also mandate upgrading your stack (*libs/tk*) as well, which would mean your existing GTK3 apps would also need upgrade... ie. you'll be upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10 - which is how Ubuntu offers it.